Offline autocue (teleprompter) program for Windows?
I'm seeking recommendations for an autocue program, which is to say, a program

into which I can input text,
which then saves it and scrolls it up my laptop screen
in a text size and at a speed of my choosing.

An autocue is also called a teleprompter.
Criteria are:

Free
Runs on Windows 11
Runs wholly offline
Does not require a Google or Apple account
Does not require the use of Chrome or any other web browser that is Chromium based, such as Edge or Opera. Ideally it won't require the use of a web browser, but if does require one and works fine with Firefox that's OK.
Does not require the use of a smartphone at any time.

The program doesn't need to concern itself with camera software, because I can run that separately.
Thanks in advance for all recommendations.

QPrompt

https://qprompt.app/
https://github.com/Cuperino/QPrompt-Teleprompter


Teleprompter software for all video creators. Built with ease of use,
productivity, control accuracy, and smooth performance in mind.



[✓] into which I can input text,
[✓] which then saves it and scrolls it up my laptop screen
[✓] in a text size and at a speed of my choosing.
[✓] Free (and open source)
[✓]  Runs on Windows 11 (Linux and macOS too)
[✓]  Runs wholly offline
[✓]  Does not require a Google or Apple account
[✓]  Does not require the use of Chrome or any other web browser that is Chromium based, such as Edge or Opera. Ideally it won't require the use of a web browser, but if does require one and works fine with Firefox that's OK.
[✓]  Does not require the use of a smartphone at any time.

